# If $\gamma(t)=3-3t^2+i(t^3-3t+1)$ on the interval $[-1,1]$, determine: $(i)\int_{\gamma}(z^2+iz)dz$ ;$(ii)\int_{\gamma}e^{\pi z}dz$ ;

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

If $\gamma(t)=3-3t^2+i(t^3-3t+1)$ on the interval $[-1,1]$, determine:

$(i)\int_{\gamma}(z^2+iz)dz$ ;$(ii)\int_{\gamma}e^{\pi z}dz$ ; $(iii)\int_{\gamma}\sin^2(\pi z)dz$

I have tried to apply the definition of line integral which says that $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$, but I can not reach an integral that is easy, could this be done in a better way? That is, I'm not saying to tell me the answer, I want to know how it is done or what methods are used to solve this type of integrals, thank you very much ....

Comment: Use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: for i), integrate $z^2+iz$ with limits at $\gamma(-1)$ and $\gamma(1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $f$ is analytic in $\Omega\subset{\mathbb C}$ and has a primitive $F$ in $\Omega$ then for all paths $\gamma\subset\Omega$ one has
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\>dz=F(b)-F(a)\ ,$$
whereby $a$ is the initial point, and $b$ is the endpoint of $\gamma$.